# How to custom the color of IconButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button

I want to custom the color of IconButton instead of using the default value set on TopAppBar, but in [android.compose.material](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#iconbutton) there is no slot api to change it.

```
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "LayoutsCodelab")
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {  // <- why it has the theme color and how to custom it.
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the **`tint`** parameter in the `Icon` composable:

```
actions = {
    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,
            "contentDescription",
            tint = Color.Red)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What about background color?

Comment: @acmpo6ou Use the `background` modifier. For example `modifier = Modifier.background(Yellow)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. But my icon is round, and `background` modifier makes a square background. I was unable to make it round since `IconButton` doesn't have a `shape` argument.

Comment: @acmpo6ou In this case you have to clip the background using: `modifier = Modifier.background(Yellow,CircleShape)`.